# Android Spinner Not Working

Tags: android, mobile, spinner

I'm trying to implement an Android spinner in my app but am running into some problems with the java file associated with the Activity its placed in.

The errors I am getting are as follows:

```
1. setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_asleep_at);
    - cannot be resolved or is not a field
2. cycles_array (where ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> is...)
    - cannot be resolved or is not a field
3. spinner (where "android.widget.Spinner spinner" is...)
    - cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

The code I have is as follows:

```
import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class DisplayAsleepAt extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_asleep_at);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        android.widget.Spinner spinner = (android.widget.Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.cycles_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
}
```

Here is the xml file I am using:

```
<Spinner 
    android:id="@+id/AA_spinner_prompt"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:prompt="@string/AA_spinner_promptTXT" 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

And here is the strings.xml file I have the array in:

```
<string-array name="cycles_array">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
    <item>5</item>
    <item>6</item>
    <item>7</item>
</string-array>
```

If anyone has any ideas as to what might have gone wrong, it would be greatly appreciated. I can always post more if you need. Thanks all.

EDIT:

Here is the entire xml file I am using. I've been looking through it for a while and can't seem to find anything wrong with it...maybe I'm just tired at this point...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/AA_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/AA_titleTXT"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        tools:context=".DisplayAsleepAt" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/AA_intro"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/AA_introTXT"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/AA_title" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/AA_button_pick"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/AA_button_pickTXT"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="showTimePickerFragment" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/AA_rem_cycles"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/AA_rem_cyclesTXT"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/AA_button_pick" />
    <Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/AA_spinner_prompt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:prompt="@string/AA_spinner_promptTXT"  />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/AA_final_time"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/AA_final_timeTXT"
        android:textSize="15dp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/AA_create_alarm_button"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/AA_create_alarm_buttonTXT"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: the name(i.e. AA_spinner_prompt) of your spinner in `xml` file is different and the your findViewById(R.id.spinner) is different.It should be findViewById(R.id.AA_spinner_prompt)

Comment: Clean your project. And, try to run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means there's something syntactically wrong with your XML layouts and R cannot be auto-generated. Try looking at your xml code and if you still have problem then post your xml code.

Change this code

```
android.widget.Spinner spinner = (android.widget.Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
```

To

```
android.widget.Spinner spinner = (android.widget.Spinner) findViewById(R.id.AA_spinner_prompt);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This should be comment not a answer

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from your code :

```
import android.R;
```

and then Clean & Rebuild your project.